# Await in node repl (started using api)

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, read-eval-print-loop, node-repl

One can run cli repl with await support like this:

```
node --experimental-repl-await
```

My question is: how do I do the same, but for repl, started from code using node [api](https://nodejs.org/api/repl.html), similar to this:

```
const repl = require('repl')

repl.start('> ')
```